# Angular 8 testing error Unexpected value 'DecoratorFactory' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'

Tags: karma-jasmine, angular8, karma-runner

I am trying to make Jasmine & Karma framework into the current angular application running in ver 8.2. But i am coming across this weird error inside the Karma test running window:

> Failed: Unexpected value 'DecoratorFactory' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

What is the problem?

My componenent.spec.ts looks like this:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';
import {HttpClientTestingModule} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';


describe('HomeComponent', () => {
  let component: HomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomeComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule, Pipe]
      ,declarations: [HomeComponent]
      ,schemas:[NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
      ,providers: [
        {provide: MsalService, useFactory: '' },
        {provide: Store, useFactory: '' }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

    it('should have header text', async(() => {
      const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
      fixture.detectChanges();
    
      const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
      //expect(compiled.querySelector('.header-txt').textContent).toContain('Tax');    
  }));
});
```

Comment: Please suggest where am i making the mistake ?

Comment: Can you remove `pipe` from `imports` and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause :-

```
export class MockStore<T> {
      private state: BehaviorSubject<T> = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);
      
      setState(data: T) { this.state.next(data); }

      select(selector?: any): Observable<T> {
        return this.state.asObservable();
      }

      pipe() {}
      dispatch(action: any) { }
}
```

========================================================================

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    {provide: Store, useFactory: 'MockStore' }
    ..............
```

The useFactory property must be some custom class name. Now i mocked the store class.